Propagate Windows routing to Windows Subsystem
I set up routing on my Windows 11 machine to be able to route some specific IP addressed (for example 1.2.3.4) to VPN.
route add 1.2.3.4 MASK 255.255.255.255 1.2.3.4
This works fine in windows.
Once I switch to Windows Subsystem the routing is not configured there (I cannot ping the server from WSL, once I can from Windows cmd).
Is there a configure Windows routing to propagate such changes to WSL routing as well?

If you to set WSL to use your Windows network setting, try setting Mirrored mode as in this answer.
